# Convert epoch time with moment.js in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs, epoch

I'm already check this [Using momentjs to convert date to epoch then back to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392280/using-momentjs-to-convert-date-to-epoch-then-back-to-date) but it still cannot solve my problem.
Before I'm used moment.js, I'm just converted my epoch time like this

**Scenario 1: Without moment.js**

```
    var val = 62460;
    var selected_time = new Date(val * 1000);
    console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), ':', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'in UTC');
```

My console log shown like this
**Selected epoch is :  62460 and the time is  17 : 21 in UTC**

**Scenario 2: With moment.js**

```
var val = 62460;
var selected_time = moment(val).format('hh:mm:ss');
console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selected_time);
```

My console log shown like this
**Selected epoch is :  62460 and the time is  08:01:02 in UTC**

The correct time is **17:21:00**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first scenario, you are multiplying by 1000, you forgot that in the second case.

```
var val = 62460
var selected_time = moment(val*1000).utc().format('hh:mm:ss');
```

Also, by default, MomentJS parses in local time. So you need to explicitly convert it to UTC.

Comment: Sorry forgot to inform, actually I'm already test it by multiplying by 1000 but the result shown 01:21:00.