# Convert epoch time to date - MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have a epoch time, which i need to convert it into human readable date

```
1643788800000
```

I'm using `moment.js`. I have the following code, which doesn't seem to work

```
moment("1643788800000", 'L')
```

This gives the moment object with `d:Invalid Date`

```
 d:Invalid Date {}
_f:"L"
_i:1643788800000
_isAMomentObject:true
_isUTC:false
_isValid:false
_locale:Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_pf:{empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(1), overflow: 1, charsLeftOver: 5, …}
```

I also tried giving with the format

```
moment("1643788800000").format('L')
```

This returns always current system date. It is not converting to the exact provided epoch date.

How to convert epoch to human readable date from moment.js
P.S i'm getting Invalid Date in moment.js object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using momentjs to convert date to epoch then back to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392280/using-momentjs-to-convert-date-to-epoch-then-back-to-date)

Comment: The dupe target seems to hold the keys to answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Long (or int) instead of string. So the proper way is

```
moment(1643788800000).format('L')
```

Comment: It works when I try it. Make sure you're using the latest version