# how to convert the date 22/04/2020 to Epoch timestamp using moment javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var date = '22/04/2020';
console.log(moment(date).format("X"));
```

log coming as NaN. Please provide a solution for, required output is 1587568445

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392280/using-momentjs-to-convert-date-to-epoch-then-back-to-date

Comment: but when i pass the date '22/04/2020'.....
var ts = moment("'22/04/2020", "M/D/YYYY").valueOf();
var m = moment(ts);
var s = m.format("M/D/YYYY");
alert("Values are: ts = " + ts);
Output: ------------

Comment: M=22 doesn't look right

Comment: var ts = moment("22/04/2020", "DD/MM/YYYY").valueOf();
var m = moment(ts);
var s = m.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
alert("Values are: ts = " + ts + ", s = " + s); -----> not working

Comment: You simply _are not_ going to get `1587568445` out of `22/04/2020` because `1587568445` is a moment in time _within_ 22/04/2020, but you are not specifying a time. See vjr12's answer, which I have upvoted. The NaN is because [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) doesn't accept the DD/MM/YYYY format. See the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using moment's unix() method. This would give epoch equivalent of "22/04/2020".

Here the time pattern has been removed, hence it results **1587340800**.

For your output, pass in 22/04/2020 20:44:05 to get **1587568445** which is the epoch equivalent

```js
var epoch = moment("22/04/2020", "DD/MM/YYYY").unix();
console.log(epoch);

var epoch1 = moment("22/04/2020 20:44:05", "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").unix();
console.log(epoch1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```